# Angular:- trying to show images from an array but getting error

Tags: angular, angular5

Below is stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oln5j3

My requirements:- I have an array which have n number of images, I need to show 3 images at once, on click, it should show another next 3 images, Supppose array length is 5 then onclick it should remaining 2 images. but shouldn't repeat the previous images. So for that I used slice method.

Please check my method and let me know where I am doing mistakes

Comment: Where is `validateMailingStreetAddress` called from, and where is `mailingAddress.address3.error` being set?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the mailingStreetAddressErrorMessage, in the same place you set the mailingStreetAddressError to false?

Comment: Here's how you implement and apply a custom validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the documentation.